# Как при сборке war с помощью maven скопировать файл в рабочую папку

Tags: maven, веб-программирование, ant

B ant записана вот такая строчка

copy verbose="on" file="${target.dir}/classes/robots.txt" todir="${build.dir}" overwrite="true"

Как то же самое сделать в maven?

Comment: http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почти любой maven плагин это умеет.

```
├── data
│   └── robots.txt
├── pom.xml
├── src
└── target
```

Например `maven-resources-plugin`:

```
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>copy-resources</id>
                 <phase>validate</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <resources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>data</directory>
                            <filtering>false</filtering>
                            <includes>
                                <include>robots.txt</include>
                            </includes>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

или `maven-war-plugin`, если у вас web приложение:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
            <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            <webResources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>${project.basedir}/data</directory>
                    <filtering>false</filtering>
                    <includes>
                        <include>robots.txt</include>
                    </includes>
                    <targetPath>../</targetPath>
                </resource>
            </webResources>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Опция `includes` работает как "белый список". Будут скопированы только файлы, перечисленные внутри данного тэга.

Comment: Правильно я понимаю, что все файлы из data скопируются? А как задать фильтр, чтобы только один robots.txt скопировался?

Comment: Да, из `data`.Корень прооекта в maven получается через плейсхолдер `${project.basedir}`. Используйте опции `includes` , `excludes`. Обновил ответ